# count saturdays before 15 date as working days and skip others

Tags: mysql

My company policy is that we count the Saturdays before 15 dates as working days and after 15 days as company holiday kindly tell me the function to count working days of the month skip all Sundays and Saturdays before 15 date in Query

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: any of them we will use that, But prefered mysql

Comment: @ juergen d MySQL

Comment: And what is the input? 2 dates?

Comment: input is start of the month and end of the same month
ie BETWEEN '2019-07-01' AND '2019-07-31'

Comment: Since you are not really selecting anything from a table you should do that in your program logic and not in SQL. SQL is designed to get data from tables and not to calculate date differences.

Comment: @ juergen d i am performing all my operation in query just stuck in that to get all working days and skip all Sundays and Saturdays before date 15

Comment: Try looking at `WEEKDAY()` https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_weekday.asp

Comment: Which version of MySQL? Try `select version();` and share the result.

Comment: 5.7.24-log MySQL version

Comment: kindly help me with this MySQL version

Comment: Clarify this, every Monday to Saturday from 1st to 15th of every month is counted as working days and after 15th, Saturdays & Sundays are considered as off-days?

Comment: @ tcadidot0  exactly every Monday to Saturday from 1st to 15th of every month is counted as working days and Sundays are off, and after 15th, both Saturdays and Sundays are considered as off-days

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I think you need a Calendar table.. unless you're using MariaDB version 10.0 above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below code to count the working days as per your requirement -

```
CREATE FUNCTION FN_CNT_Working_days(StartDate DATE,
                                    EndDate   DATE) 
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
     DECLARE WORKING_DAYS INT;
     SELECT
   (DATEDIFF(EndDate, DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(EndDate), '-', MONTH(EndDate), '-', 16))) + 1)
  -(FLOOR(DATEDIFF(EndDate, DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(EndDate), '-', MONTH(EndDate), '-', 16)))/7) * 2)
  -(CASE WHEN DAYNAME(DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(EndDate), '-', MONTH(EndDate), '-', 16))) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  -(CASE WHEN DAYNAME(EndDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
   +
   (DATEDIFF(DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(EndDate), '-', MONTH(EndDate), '-', 15)), StartDate) + 1)
  -(FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(EndDate), '-', MONTH(EndDate), '-', 15)), StartDate)/7))
  -(CASE WHEN DAYNAME(StartDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
     INTO WORKING_DAYS;

     RETURN (WORKING_DAYS);
END;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=556f93ddbd5f590577ff3f46b4224226) is the fiddle. Also you need to take care of holidays along with this code.

Comment: one more fever I want from you make it as a function which takes two dates so I can use it anywhere

Answer (score 2):

You can try either one method below or can use the query which was shared by @Ankit.

If you have a table like calendar it will be useful in many ways.

**METHOD: 1**

If you have a Calendar table you can run the below query,

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN WEEKDAY(cal.cal_date) <> 6 AND DAY(cal.cal_date) < 16 THEN 1
             WHEN WEEKDAY(cal.cal_date) NOT IN (5, 6) AND DAY(cal.cal_date) > 15 THEN 1 END) AS 'working days'
FROM 
    calendar cal
WHERE 
    cal.cal_date BETWEEN '2019-10-01' AND '2019-10-31';
```

**METHOD: 2**

If creating a TABLE OR VIEW is restricted can generate a range of dates using the below query

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN WEEKDAY(cal.cal_date) <> 6 AND DAY(cal.cal_date) < 16 THEN 1
             WHEN WEEKDAY(cal.cal_date) NOT IN (5, 6) AND DAY(cal.cal_date) > 15 THEN 1 END) AS 'working days'
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        ('1970-01-01' + INTERVAL (((((`t4`.`t4` * 10000) + (`t3`.`t3` * 1000)) + (`t2`.`t2` * 100)) + (`t1`.`t1` * 10)) + `t0`.`t0`) DAY) AS `cal_date`
    FROM
        ((((((SELECT 0 AS `t0`) UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS `1` UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS `2` UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS `3` UNION ALL SELECT 4 AS `4` UNION ALL SELECT 5 AS `5` UNION ALL SELECT 6 AS `6` UNION ALL SELECT 7 AS `7` UNION ALL SELECT 8 AS `8` UNION ALL SELECT 9 AS `9`) `t0`
        JOIN (SELECT 0 AS `t1` UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS `1` UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS `2` UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS `3` UNION ALL SELECT 4 AS `4` UNION ALL SELECT 5 AS `5` UNION ALL SELECT 6 AS `6` UNION ALL SELECT 7 AS `7` UNION ALL SELECT 8 AS `8` UNION ALL SELECT 9 AS `9`) `t1`)
        JOIN (SELECT 0 AS `t2` UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS `1` UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS `2` UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS `3` UNION ALL SELECT 4 AS `4` UNION ALL SELECT 5 AS `5` UNION ALL SELECT 6 AS `6` UNION ALL SELECT 7 AS `7` UNION ALL SELECT 8 AS `8` UNION ALL SELECT 9 AS `9`) `t2`)
        JOIN (SELECT 0 AS `t3` UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS `1` UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS `2` UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS `3` UNION ALL SELECT 4 AS `4` UNION ALL SELECT 5 AS `5` UNION ALL SELECT 6 AS `6` UNION ALL SELECT 7 AS `7` UNION ALL SELECT 8 AS `8` UNION ALL SELECT 9 AS `9`) `t3`)
        JOIN (SELECT 0 AS `t4` UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS `1` UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS `2` UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS `3` UNION ALL SELECT 4 AS `4` UNION ALL SELECT 5 AS `5` UNION ALL SELECT 6 AS `6` UNION ALL SELECT 7 AS `7` UNION ALL SELECT 8 AS `8` UNION ALL SELECT 9 AS `9`) `t4`)) AS cal
WHERE 
    cal.cal_date BETWEEN '2019-10-01' AND '2019-10-31';
```

Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=7bd5e5aa6968357808f1a057f14a5ec3)

Comment: @ tcadidot0 @Ankit Bajpai dear one thing also I needed is to skip the public holidays also from working days the are in  hr_holidays table and are from and to date so please help  me

Comment: @sarfarazahmed It would be nice if you ask new question instead of old post which already answered.

Answer (score 2):

This works without calendar table and by month. And you only need to change the date value @curdt variable. It can be any dates within the month as long as its not less or more than the real calendar dates e.g '2019-07-00' or '2019-07-32' - this won't work.

```
#1 : Setting variable.
SET @curdt := '2019-07-01'; #only need to change the date here.
SET @startdate := LAST_DAY(@curdt-INTERVAL 1 MONTH)+INTERVAL 1 DAY;
SET @lastdate := LAST_DAY(@curdt);

#2 : Count workdays. 

SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN DAY(dt) <= 15 AND WEEKDAY(dt)=6 THEN 0
            WHEN DAY(dt) > 15 AND WEEKDAY(dt) IN (5,6) THEN 0
            ELSE 1 END) AS Workdays 
FROM
(SELECT dt 
 FROM   (
         #custom calendar
         SELECT CONCAT_WS('-',curmy,CONCAT(n2,n1)) dt 
         FROM
                (SELECT 0 AS n1 UNION 
                 SELECT 1 UNION
                 SELECT 2 UNION
                 SELECT 3 UNION
                 SELECT 4 UNION
                 SELECT 5 UNION
                 SELECT 6 UNION
                 SELECT 7 UNION
                 SELECT 8 UNION
                 SELECT 9 ) a CROSS JOIN
                (SELECT 0 n2 UNION 
                 SELECT 1 UNION 
                 SELECT 2 UNION 
                 SELECT 3) b CROSS JOIN
                (SELECT LEFT(@curdt,7) curmy) c
          ) zz
 WHERE  dt BETWEEN @startdate AND @lastdate) XX
 GROUP BY MONTH(dt);
```

Just tried a new query and might just add in here for future reference:

```
SET @curdate := CURDATE()-INTERVAL 1 MONTH;

SELECT * FROM
(SELECT CONCAT_WS('-',df,CONCAT(b,c)) dm FROM 
(SELECT DATE_FORMAT(@curdate, '%Y-%m') df) a CROSS JOIN
(SELECT 0 b UNION SELECT 1 b UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3) b CROSS JOIN
(SELECT 0 c UNION
SELECT 1 UNION
SELECT 2 UNION
SELECT 3 UNION
SELECT 4 UNION
SELECT 5 UNION
SELECT 6 UNION
SELECT 7 UNION
SELECT 8 UNION
SELECT 9) c) d WHERE DAY(dm) BETWEEN 1 AND DAY(LAST_DAY(dm))
ORDER BY dm;
```

This method is for MariaDB - using it's sequence engine:
[From MariaDB 10.1, the Sequence engine is installed by default.](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sequence-storage-engine/)

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT_WS('-',a.seq,b.seq,c.seq), '%Y-%m-%d') dates
   FROM seq_2020_to_2021 a -- year range
   CROSS JOIN seq_1_to_12 b -- month range
   CROSS JOIN seq_1_to_31 c  -- day range
HAVING dates IS NOT NULL; -- excluding invalid dates returned as NULL
```