# How to group by date (SELECT if null then 0) MYSQL

Tags: mysql

How do I get counts data grouped by every day in range date even if data is not present i.e. IF 0 will select 0

This my sample data and query [MYSQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/545b31/5)

**Input**

```
create table t_order(
  order_id int
  ,qty int
  ,time datetime 
);

insert into t_order values (1,2,'2020-02-17 08:00:00.000');
insert into t_order values (2,1,'2020-02-18 10:00:00.000');
insert into t_order values (3,3,'2020-02-20 08:00:00.000');
insert into t_order values (4,1,'2020-02-20 10:00:00.000');
insert into t_order values (5,7,'2020-02-21 08:00:00.000');
insert into t_order values (6,1,'2020-02-23 10:00:00.000');
insert into t_order values (7,1,'2020-02-24 08:00:00.000');
insert into t_order values (8,2,'2020-02-24 10:00:00.000');
insert into t_order values (9,1,'2020-02-25 08:00:00.000');
insert into t_order values (10,1,'2020-02-26 10:00:00.000');
```

**Implementation**

```
SELECT
  SUM(qty) as total,
  DATE(time) as date
FROM t_order
where 
  DATE(TIME) between date('2020-02-15') and date('2020-02-26')
GROUP BY CAST(time AS date)
```

**Actual Output**:

```
total   date
2   2020-02-17
1   2020-02-18
4   2020-02-20
7   2020-02-21
1   2020-02-23
3   2020-02-24
1   2020-02-25
1   2020-02-26
```

My expectation code show every date by range date parameter event data is 0 or null:

**Expected Output**

```
  total date
0   2020-02-15
0   2020-02-16
2   2020-02-17
1   2020-02-18
0   2020-02-19
4   2020-02-20
7   2020-02-21
0   2020-02-22
1   2020-02-23
3   2020-02-24
1   2020-02-25
1   2020-02-26
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only select data that exists in the database.

To achieve what you want, create a separate table (a temporary one or permanent calendar table) that contains all the dates in your desired date range and include that (join) with your query.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a calendar table. If you're using MariaDB (v10.1 above), there's an easy way to generate a temporary calendar table. With MySQL however, you'll going to use longer query (not sure in latest MySQL version though). Refer following example:

```
SELECT ADDDATE('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) as dates FROM
(SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t0,
(SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t1,
(SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t2,
(SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t3,
(SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t4;
```

This will generate a date range from '1970-01-01' to '2243-10-16' in MySQL but of course you can change it accordingly. To create a `calendar` table, I've prepared a fiddle here : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qVgmfDaVUszABAyFzH7iUS/3

I have also previously provide a suggestion for shorter date range here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/58443510/10910692 inclusive of MariaDB suggestion; which is much shorter query to generate dates/calendar.

Now if you don't create a `calendar` table, using this method your query will look something like this:

```
SELECT IFNULL(B.Total,0) AS Total, A.dates AS Date FROM
(SELECT ADDDATE('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) as dates FROM
(SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t0,
(SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t1,
(SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t2,
(SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t3,
(SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) t4) A 
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT
  SUM(qty) as total,
  DATE(time) as date
FROM t_order
where 
  DATE(TIME) between date('2020-02-15') and date('2020-02-26')
GROUP BY CAST(time AS date)) B 
ON A.dates=B.date
WHERE A.dates BETWEEN '2020-02-15 and '2020-02-26';
```

It looks ridiculously long and unnecessary. But with a `calendar` table, you just need to do:

```
SELECT IFNULL(B.Total,0) AS Total, A.dates AS Date 
FROM calendar A
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT
  SUM(qty) as total,
  DATE(time) as date
FROM t_order
where 
  DATE(TIME) between date('2020-02-15') and date('2020-02-26')
GROUP BY CAST(time AS date)) B 
ON A.dates=B.date
WHERE A.dates BETWEEN '2020-02-15 and '2020-02-26';
```