# Getting zero value from empty days

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to return the count of item sold in last 30 days and
return 0 if there is no item sold. My current query is working well for
getting days where there is item sold but it is not returning 0 values and
I need it.

Here is my current query

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(purchase_date), '%m/%d') AS Dates, COUNT(*) AS COUNT 
FROM purchases
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(purchase_date) BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
GROUP BY Dates
ORDER BY Dates ASC
```

The actual result are:

```
02/15 -> 10
02/16 -> 12
02/18 -> 22
```

But I'm missing the empty date(s) that I want to return as 0.

This is the table structure:

```
userid int(11), purchase_item int(11), purchase_date int(11)
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: MySQL or MariaDB? What version?

Comment: pretty sure it is mysql

Comment: You also need to tell us what version you're using

Comment: i think it is 5.7.31

Comment: The way I see it, you'll need a calendar table or at least a query to generate dates then `left join` it to your query.

Comment: i had a friend that was able to do it in a single query but unfortunately he is dead now and i lost that query

Comment: Oh no, I'm sorry for your loss. Take a look here for some ideas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58425598/count-saturdays-before-15-date-as-working-days-and-skip-others

Answer (score 3):

You can generate the last 30 days using a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive dates as (
      select curdate() as dte, 1 as n
      union all
      select dte - interval 1 day, n + 1
      from dates
      where n < 30
     )
```

The rest is just incorporating this into a query using a `LEFT JOIN` or correlate subquery:

```
with recursive dates as (
      select curdate() as dte, 1 as n
      union all
      select dte - interval 1 day, n + 1
      from dates
      where n < 30
     ) 
select d.dte, count(p.purchase_date)
from dates d left join
     purchases p
     on from_unixtime(purchase_date) >= d.dte and
        from_unixtime(purchase_date) < d.dte + interval 1 day
group by d.dte;
```